# Incorrect port forwarding with ZTE H368N

Tags: networking, router, ip, port-forwarding, ip-address

I'm trying to forward my local server running on XAMPP on port 80 to be available on my IPv4 address. I created a new entry, with these details:

[image: image of the entry]

but when I enter my IPv4 address I only see this page

[image: router page]

with the login and password.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Accessing the web server public IP from your private network will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning? - NYC Networkers](https://web.archive.org/web/20181017232841/https://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Comment: Ask a friend to try to check if they can get to your server. If that works, the config is correct. If you want to access it from internal network, you need to go to 192.168.1.10.

Comment: @adamhomonnay did you have a chance to look at my answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you need to set up TCP for the HTTP protocol (there are [some exceptions though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323351/does-http-use-udp)).

However as Peregrino69 states correctly some consumer-grade routers will require you to use the internal address when you try to access the forwarded port (otherwise they route you to the router's HTTP-server). On some routers even if this isn't enough, then your only option is to use a different port for your xampp server. I've seen this behavior on several models.